# Set new layer to SVG marker in plugin QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, markers, svg

Im trying to create a new layer and change it to SVG marker and set blue-marker.svg as the marker but its not working.

Here is what i have:

```
        iface.addVectorLayer( "Point", "marker_layer", "memory")
        mlayer = self.iface.activeLayer()
        symbol = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(mlayer.geometryType())
        svgStyle = {}
        svgStyle['name'] = '/usr/share/qgis/svg/symbol/blue-marker.svg'
        svgStyle['outline'] = '#000000'
        svgStyle['outline-width'] = '0'
        svgStyle['size'] = '6'
        symbol_layer = QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayerV2.create(svgStyle)
        symbol.changeSymbolLayer(0, symbol_layer)
```

Im not getting any errors but the new layer is not set as SVG neither is the default marker to blue-marker.svg

EDIT:
here is the solution:

```
        layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
        svgStyle = {}
        svgStyle['name'] = '/usr/share/qgis/svg/symbol/blue-marker.svg'
        svgStyle['outline'] = '#000000'
        svgStyle['outline-width'] = '0'
        svgStyle['size'] = '12'
        symbol_layer = QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayerV2.create(svgStyle)
        layer.rendererV2().symbols()[0].changeSymbolLayer(0, symbol_layer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on this approach [Using SVG for layer symbols](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/application_development/9781783984985/5/ch05lvl1sec94/using-svg-for-layer-symbols)

First, we'll define the path to the shapefile:

```
Copy  
src = "/Users/joellawhead/qgis_data/NYC_MUSEUMS_GEO/NYC_MUSEUMS_GEO.shp"
```

Next, we'll load the layer:

```
Copy  
lyr = QgsVectorLayer(src, "Museums", "ogr")
```

Now, we define the properties of the symbol, including the location of the SVG file as a Python dictionary:

```
Copy
svgStyle = {}
svgStyle['fill'] = '#0000ff'
svgStyle['name'] = 'landmark/tourism=museum.svg'
svgStyle['outline'] = '#000000'
svgStyle['outline-width'] = '6.8'
svgStyle['size'] = '6'
```

Then, we create an SVG symbol layer:

```
Copy
symLyr1...
```

Comment: Isnt the layer already loaded? the solution you are giving is the same im using but you'r loading a layer when i want to use an existing layer (marker_layer)

Comment: Try loading the layer and see how it works out first.

Comment: i dont have that layer

Comment: Try loading (marker_layer)